# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with Metal Sampler State

Tags: runtime-error, exc-bad-access, metal

So I'm getting the annoying EXC_BAD_ACCESS error...

With zombies I see that it's the MTLSamplerState that has to do with the crash:

```
*** -[MTLDebugSamplerState retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1c9065c40
```

This is how I declare it:

```
let sampler_descriptor = MTLSamplerDescriptor()
sampler_descriptor.minFilter = .linear
sampler_descriptor.magFilter = .linear
sampler_descriptor.sAddressMode = .clampToZero
sampler_descriptor.tAddressMode = .clampToZero
let sampler_state = self.device!.makeSamplerState(descriptor: sampler_descriptor)!
```

I later in the same function, where the error happens, I access the sampler like this:

```
renderCommandEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(sampler_state, index: 0)
```

The crash happens randomly at different times in my program, but not always, not sure how to debug in further...

Why would sampler_state be deallocated? Isn't Swift suppose to do ARC?

**Update:**

Here's the stack trace:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18339161c)
frame #0: 0x000000018339161c CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 1180
frame #1: 0x00000001832770dc CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
* frame #2: 0x00000001020c2b14 Test App`MetalView.render(view=0x0000000105111000, self=0x0000000105111000) at MetalView.swift:378
frame #3: 0x00000001020c0d38 Test App`closure #1 in MetalView.draw(rect=(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 112.5, height = 112.5)), self=0x0000000105111000) at MetalView.swift:238
frame #4: 0x00000001020c36dc Test App`thunk for @callee_owned () -> (@error @owned Error) at MetalView.swift:0
frame #5: 0x00000001020c6ff0 Test App`partial apply for thunk for @callee_owned () -> (@error @owned Error) at MetalView.swift:0
frame #6: 0x0000000103c24e1c libswiftObjectiveC.dylib`ObjectiveC.autoreleasepool<A>(invoking: () throws -> A) throws -> A + 68
frame #7: 0x00000001020c0c0c Test App`MetalView.draw(rect=(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 112.5, height = 112.5)), self=0x0000000105111000) at MetalView.swift:240
frame #8: 0x00000001020c3798 Test App`@objc MetalView.draw(_:) at MetalView.swift:0
frame #9: 0x0000000196844ed0 MetalKit`-[MTKView draw] + 140
frame #10: 0x0000000187368010 QuartzCore`-[CALayer display] + 188
frame #11: 0x00000001872dbfdc QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 520
frame #12: 0x0000000187302340 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 540
frame #13: 0x00000001872570d4 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 928
frame #14: 0x0000000187307fa4 QuartzCore`display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 236
frame #15: 0x000000018331a080 CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 188
frame #16: 0x00000001833349dc CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
frame #17: 0x00000001833340e0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 440
frame #18: 0x0000000183331bb4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2196
frame #19: 0x00000001832522d8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
frame #20: 0x00000001850e3f84 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 100
frame #21: 0x000000018c7ff880 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 208
frame #22: 0x000000010231a1e8 Test App`main at AppDelegate.swift:13
frame #23: 0x0000000182d7656c libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Comment: What's the stack trace at the point of the crash? That might provide some clues.

Comment: @KenThomases I've now added the stack trace to the post.